# what parameterized type should be for a "List" of different classes in Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

what parameterized type should be for the "List" below?

```
  List<Class<?>> supportedClasses = Arrays.asList(String.class, Integer.class, Long.class);
```

according to IDEA
[image]

I tried

[image]

also

[image]

but they all have grammer error

Comment: What are you using that list for?

Comment: Please paste code as text rather than images. Would you please explain you want a diverse list rather than three separate lists?

Comment: @NomadMaker there separate lists? no, it is only one list of different classes

Comment: @lily I know you only want one list. I want to know why you insist on only one list. This goes against many pop principles, but you must have a reason.

Comment: @NomadMaker: I think a `List<Class<?>>` is very reasonable. Your suggestion, of having a separate list for every element, makes no sense to me: why even use `List` at that point?

Answer (score 5):

Since the elements of your list are of type, `Class`, your list should be of type, `List<Class<?>>`

```
List<Class<?>> supportedClasses = Arrays.asList(String.class, Integer.class, Long.class);
```

Comment: `Class` is a generic type itself, so that should be at least `List<Class<?>>`.

Comment: `extends Object` is redundant.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu - Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the answer to incorporate the same.

Comment: IDEA prompts it is not ok @LiveandLetLive

Comment: @lily - I do not see any problem either in Eclipse or in IDEA.

Comment: @LiveandLetLive pls see my captured snapshots , also I tried to compile it and it says "Imcomptible type: java.util.List<java.lang.Class<? extends java.lang.Object&java.io.Serializable&java.lang.Comparable<? extends java.lang.Object&java.io.Serializable&java.lang.Comparable<?>>>> can't be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.Class<?>>"

Comment: @lily - The problem is that you have not imported the required types. Please put `import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;` at the top of your code and it will be fine.

Comment: @LiveandLetLive of course they are imported

Comment: @lily - I just wrote a minimal reproducible code, `import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Class<?>> supportedClasses = Arrays.asList(String.class, Integer.class, Long.class);
        System.out.println(supportedClasses);
    }
}` in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.3 and the code got compiled and executed successfully.

Comment: @LiveandLetLive maybe it is because my project jdk version is 7? I tried in java 8, List<Class<?>> is OK

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs in Java 7 because the compiler cannot infer the type of the list returned from `Arrays.asList`. [JEP 101](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101), released in Java 8, adds this functionality. The workaround for Java 7 is to explicitly specify the method type parameter:

```
List<Class<?>> supportedClasses = Arrays.<Class<?>>asList(String.class, Integer.class, Long.class);
```